# Derived function slope to the given function

Tags: functions, slope

**Preface:**
I'm just a musician, trying to understand some math. Don't blame me, please ;)
**Synopsis:**
Given next 5 images, calculate slope of the proportion function. Make so the highest proportion is determined by the input **n**
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkSrV.png),
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNDsM.png),
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJz7d.png),
[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRraq.png),
[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKxO1.png)
**Description:**
You can see 5 screenshots from the program FabFilter C-2. I need to do exactly the same mathematically with changing max number (max right position of the knob).
**My thoughts:**
I tried 2 fixed number - 10 and 200 (+1 is because of starting from 1; 200 is input **n**):

```
1: f1(x) = 9x + 1
2: f2(x) = 199x + 1
3: f3(x) = f2 / f1
4: f4(x) = x * (9.95 * f3) + 1
```

This example works well for fixed inputs (coefficients). But for any other coefficient in *f2*
it's a mess. Plus the slope is more linear than it should be.
**Edit:**
I made a mistake. I started to describe it as 1 to 10 linear function. But it should be 0 through 1 or 1 through 2. So, for each given 0<=x<=1 we have to construct a non-linear function so that f(0)=1, f(0.5)=3, f(1)=100. But the last number (100) can be changed, so that f(0.5) has to change somehow too..

**Edit 2:**
I found the solution for the domain [0,1] and the f(1)=200 on this [site](https://www.dcode.fr/function-equation-finder). I choose an EXPONENTIAL USING CURVE FITTING option.
It is

> f(x)≈2.32033e^(4.46319x)−1.32027

There should be an explanation)
**P.S.:**
I appreciate every answer! Thanks

Comment: You need to give us a lot more context. I think what you're looking for is called the derivative.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I'm trying to create a knob in Reaktor, which inputs are from 1 to 10 linearly. And output a value, so that it is rising slowly about half a knob's way, and than rising rapidly.

Comment: I still do not understand what it is you want. Do you desire a function, whose domain is $[1, 10]$ (i.e., all real numbers between $1$ and $10$) that outputs... what? I don't think the "knobs" you've provided help at all. Please edit your original post and describe what exactly you need (and perhaps give example outputs).

Comment: @SeanRoberson, have you seen the images? On them you can find that: the value on the left side of "proportion" rising slowly almost half way through the knob's path. And than it starts growing faster. So at x=0 you have 1, and at x=1 you have 100, as well as at x=0.5 you have around 2.73. So the function that determines output is non-linear (probably quadratic). I have to calculate coefficients based on the input, that determines the max value (e.g. x=1, y = input). I don't know how to explain better :(

Comment: @SeanRoberson, yes, I made a mistake. I started to describe it as 1 to 10 linear function. But it should be 0 through 1 or 1 through 2. So, for each given 0<=x<=1 we have to construct a non-linear function so that f(0)=1, f(0.5)=3, f(1)=100. But the last number (100) can be changed, so that f(0.5) has to change somehow too..

Comment: Click the "Edit" button in the original post and add these details there, so people do not have to sift through comments. Try to remove the software bit from it (because for now it seems you're trying to do some sort of spline interpolation).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139134/discussion-between-sean-roberson-and-eugene-zolotuhin).